# Create copy of `pd.Index` with new values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, reindex

#### Example: `pd.DatetimeIndex`

Let's say I have a `pd.DatetimeIndex`, for example

```
di = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', periods=3, freq='B')

# di
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-03', '2000-01-04', '2000-01-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

I now want a new `pd.DatetimeIndex` just like `di`, but containing the values

```
v = [pd.Timestamp('2000-01-10'), pd.Timestamp('2000-01-11')]
```

I might try this

```
new_di = di.reindex(v)[0]

#new_di
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-10', '2000-01-11'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

But notice `freq=None`, so this doesn't solve my problem.

In fact, I'm even allowed to do this

```
totally_new_di = di.reindex([1, 2, 3])[0]

# totally_new_di
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

**Edit (thanks @mozway)**:

I could do

```
new_di = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-10', '2000-01-11'], freq=di.freq)
```

but this would require me to match `di` with the `pd.DatetimeIndex` constructor and its arguments, which I am trying to avoid.

#### Example `pd.CategoricalIndex`

Another example is this

```
ci = pd.CategoricalIndex(['A', 'B'], categories=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# ci
CategoricalIndex(['A', 'B'], categories=['A', 'B', 'C'], ordered=False, dtype='category')
```

There seems to be no instance method of `ci` which creates the object

```
CategoricalIndex(['B', 'C'], categories=['A', 'B', 'C'], ordered=False, dtype='category')
```

given the values `['B', 'C']`.

---

**My question**: Given an instance of `pd.Index`, how can I create a new instance of the same type where all attributes are the same, except the values have been updated? I am trying to avoid calling constructors in a family of `if isinstance`-statements.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`pandas.DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) directly?

```
new_di = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-10', '2000-01-11'], freq='B')
```

or, to match `di` programmatically:

```
new_di = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-10', '2000-01-11'], freq=di.freq)
```

output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-10', '2000-01-11'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Comment: Yes, that would naturally work but it's what I'm trying to avoid (see my comment at the end). More generally, I have _some_ instance `i` of `pd.Index`, it could be a `pd.DatetimeIndex` or `pd.CategoricalIndex` or something else. I don't want to have to match the type of `i` to any constructors. Doing that would require me to browse the `pandas` documentation to make sure I covered all the classes, and keep updating my code in case a new subclass of `pd.Index` appears in newer versions.

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: I have a `pd.MultiIndex` `mi`. I persist `mi.values` in a (Cassandra) database using an appropriate database representation. I also persist `mi[[]]` (an empty version of the same `pd.MultiIndex`) as a blob.

I then retrieve both components (the values and the empty `pd.MultiIndex`) back from the database and try to reconstruct the original `mi`, together with all the bells and whistles that the individual `mi.levels` come with.

At the moment I use `pd.MultiIndex.reindex`, but it falls short for the reasons I demonstrate above.